# I can't receive any data with websocket

Tags: vb.net, sockets, websocket

I am trying to create a bot that reads the direct messages using websocket, to avoid the ratelimit.

The problem is I don`t know much about websocket.
I googled a bit and I found some code and I used it but it don't receive anything but empty text.

This is my code

```
        Dim ws = New System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, c, h, d) True
        With ws.Options
        .SetRequestHeader("Origin", "https://www.instagram.com")
        .SetRequestHeader("Cookie", "don`t care about this")
        End With
        Try
            Await ws.ConnectAsync(New Uri("wss://edge-chat.instagram.com/chat"), Nothing)
            Console.WriteLine("state: " & ws.State.ToString)
            If (ws.State = WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open) Then
                Console.WriteLine("state: " & ws.State.ToString)
                Dim bytes(4096) As Byte
                Dim answ = New ArraySegment(Of Byte)(bytes)
                Await ws.ReceiveAsync(answ, Nothing)
                Console.WriteLine("answer:" + Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(answ.Array))
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Not opened?!")
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error." & e.Message)
        End Try
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Function
```

I see the request in the httpdebugger but I don't know why I don't get any data.

Is the problem in my code or have I misunderstood websocket.

Comment: There's nothing wrong that's blindingly obvious.  Note that your code as written will only get one chunk of the message if it's longer than 4096 bytes; you should loop until the response returned from `ReceiveAsync` (which you are currently ignoring) has `EndOfMessage` set.  In my code, I use a `List(Of Byte)` to assemble the entire message.